# Focus preservation in i3wm

Tags: window-manager, i3, window, focus

***tl;dr:*** 
**How do I implement the no_focus directive in i3wm and how do I dynamically assign a program to a workspace based on the workspace where I key the binding to open the program (i.e., I press the keybinding on `workspace n` and it opens on `workspace n` even if my focus has changed to `workspace n + 1` before the program has fully loaded)?**

**Context:** I have a handful of keybindings in i3wm (i3-gaps on Arch, to be specific) that I use, e.g.

```
bindsym $mod+Shift+W exec chromium
bindsym $mod+Shift+I exec chromium --incognito
bindsym $mod+Shift+F exec firefox
```

But I dislike the focus stealing of newly opened windows and especially dislike the behavior where I'm on `workspace n`, jump to `workspace n + 1` to hit my keybinding, jump back to `workspace n` to continue performing some task in terminal while I wait for the program to load, and, lo, the program loads on my current `workspace n` instead of `workspace n + 1` where I hit the keybinding.

I have found [this explanation](https://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#_don_8217_t_focus_window_upon_opening) in the i3wm documentation discussing exactly what I want in terms of window focusing but cannot find a single example command that I can modify: `no_focus [window_role="pop-up"]`, the example they give, does not make sense to me. I have tried `exec no_focus chromium`, `no_focus exec chromium` and a handful of less sensible combinations and none of them seem to work: I do not know how to implement the command.

I also am unsure, once I get it to work, if keying in a binding on a work space will force the program to open on that work space rather than following me to my new workspace. I know of workspace assignment (never implemented it, but that is another question) but would prefer to have a dynamic workspace assignment like I've been detailing: workspace assignment based on the workspace the keybinding is executed.